# Which file determines the default desktop manager?

Tags: kde, desktop-environments, plasma

Which configuration file determines the default desktop manager?

How can I modify this file via terminal; and not by mouse click here, **for all users at once**?

[image]

I tried to use `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`.
But it doesn't work when I add `DefaultSession=plasma.desktop` to the `[daemon]` section.

Comment: it's not a duplicate, because in that old topic was settings for single user, but I need solution to make this config for all users at once. Kinda skel or something like.